# Any parametrization $h\colon S^1\to \Gamma$ possible?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, parametrization

Consider 
[the following model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FitzHugh%E2%80%93Nagumo_model), and, in particular, the second picture given in the link, namely the blue line which represents a trajectory which I call $\Gamma$.

Is it possible to give any parametrization $h\colon S^1\to\Gamma$, where $S^1$ is the unit sphere?

I think this should be possible to find auch a bijective map. Intuitively, the sphere and the trajectorie rather look "equivalently". Maybe something like the following:

Let $\gamma\in\Gamma$ a point on the trajectory. Then $\gamma=h(s)$ where $s$ is the point on the unit sphere with "appropriate" angles.

Comment: So, do you want a concrete example of mapping or do you want just establish the fact that periodic orbit is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: The latter; just to know that if I have a curve like that trajectory (on which we are moving clock- or anticlockwise) then there is a parametrization arising from the sphere $S^1$.

Comment: If you have a flow $\phi^t$ and some $T$-periodic orbit $\gamma$ that passes through point $x_0$, then for each point $x$ of $\gamma$ you  have unique time $t_x \in \lbrack 0, T )$  such that $\phi^{t_x} (x_0) = x $. Then mappings $ x \mapsto t_x \mapsto e^{\frac{2 \pi i t_x}{T}}$ define a homeomorphism between $\gamma$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$.